# X's chances of doing or the chances of X doing

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

**Which one of the following is correct? and which one is idiomatic?**

> 1. This is because a proper education will enhance **the chances of women reaching** high-level positions, consequently, the percentage of female senior managers will increase eventually.
> 2. This because a proper education will enhance **women's chances of reaching** high-level positions................
> 3. This because a proper education will enhance **the chances of women to reach** high-level positions................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three phrases:

1. the chances of women reaching high-level positions
2. women's chances of reaching high-level positions
3. the chances of women to reach high-level positions

are all correct. The first two are equivalent, while the third has a similar but not exactly the same meaning. "Chances of reaching" (#2 and equivalently #1) describes a probability of a random event, or statistical frequency. "Chance to reach" (#3) describes an opportunity, or a path that may be pursued by choice. ([More on this difference](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/preposition-review-1-chance-of-vs-chance-for/))

The difference between the first two sentences seems to be a matter of style or preferred emphasis. The third one may be more adequate semantically due to the beginning of the sentence - education does indeed create more opportunity, so it *enhances* women's chances to reach (...) (and statistically it *increases* the chances of them reaching (...) - it is a subtle difference).

The first suggested sentence seems incorrect in another aspect - using "consequently" as a conjunction. Compound sentences with "and consequently" are more common (see [here](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-use-the-word-consequently-in-a-sentence) and [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consequently#examples) for examples). Alternatively, "consequently" can be used as a [conjunctive adverb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb) starting a new sentence (like "alternatively" in this one) or preceded by a semicolon.

If any of the other sentences (which are incomplete) is different in that aspect, that might be a reason to prefer it over the first one.

Answer (score 0):

None of them are really *idiomatic*, per se. However, the third one seems grammatically incorrect. You shouldn't say:

> the chances to reach

Instead, your first example works fine:

> the chances **of reaching**

Your second example also works fine. Truly, you can say either the first or second, but *avoid the third* because it doesn't work, grammatically...

Comment: What is wrong with "the chances to reach"? You can say "she has a chance to reach a high-level position", it is [about as common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chance+to+reach%2C+chance+of+reaching&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchance%20to%20reach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchance%20of%20reaching%3B%2Cc0) as "a chance of reaching".

Comment: @laugh - Yes, you can. But you can't say "the chances of her to reach a high-level position." First of all, it sounds awkward. Second of all, it probably sounds awkward because it's not grammatically correct!

Answer (score 0):

1 & 2 both seem acceptable, but 2 reads more elegantly, possibly because of the alliteration created with women'**s** chance**s**.

These sentences are complex and have many multi-syllable words - it may help the reader therefore, to go with the option that reads more easily, with more natural breathing.